# What are the London Olympics 2012 official camera equipment restrictions?

Tags: lens, security, olympics2012

Is there any official information on restriction on equipment length for the Olympics 2012 field events. It's been said that camera and lens must fit into a 30x20x20 bag.

Comment: http://www.itproportal.com/2012/05/09/olympics-2012-the-probable-camera-restrictions/ repeats the information you've already got, but doesn't quote an official source. It also mentions that he bag has to be able to fit under your seat.

Comment: http://www.bjp-online.com/british-journal-of-photography/news/2191402/london-2012-olympic-games-organisers-refuse-to-clarify-photography-rules-in-advance states that the rules will vary from site to site (with Wembley banning "professional-style cameras [any camera with interchangeable lenses]")

Answer (score 7):

In the official published list of [Prohibited and Restricted Items](http://www.london2012.com/mm/Document/Documents/General/01/25/44/06/Prohibitedandrestricteditemslists_Neutral.pdf) from the official [London 2012 web site](http://www.london2012.com/) it states:

> Large photographic and broadcast 
>   equipment over 30cm in length, 
>   including tripods and monopods. 
>   You cannot use photographic 
>   or broadcast equipment for 
>   commercial purposes unless you 
>   hold media accreditation

Hope that helps.

Comment: "Sir, I attest that my tripod is less than 30 cm long. Yes, I know that folded is about 80 cm *tall* but as You can see the rule is about length..."

Answer (score 5):

The official stance on photgraphy restrictions has yet to be reasleased although there have been several websites reporting on it.

**Equipment Restrictions**
*Now the company is looking at restricting what equipment can be brought in. A spokesperson for LOCOG said: "Obviously we recognise that spectators will want to bring cameras into the Games. The only restrictions are around size, and these restrictions are to prevent undue impact on other spectators."
A book released this year entitled Capture the Moment - A practical guide to taking photos at London 2012 explains: "You are allowed to take camera phones, compact cameras and DSLRs into Olympic and Paralympic venues, as long as the equipment fits into a bag no bigger than 30 x 20 x 20cm. Anything above this may be confiscated and not necessarily returned to you." 
The bag must fit under your seat, and large lenses will not be permitted because they could obstruct the others' views.
Bags could also face an X-ray check before they can be taken into the stadium. There has been some speculation as to whether all security guards will adhere to photography guidelines.*

**The rule book**

*Although the official guidelines have yet to be released, the terms and conditions online give some indication of the rules to come.*

Taken from: 
http://www.techradar.com/news/photography-video-capture/cameras/camera-restrictions-at-the-olympics-explored-1078508

T&C's from London2012 http://www.tickets.london2012.com/purchaseterms.html 
Section 19.2.3 onwards.

Happy snapping!

Answer (score 4):

I took my 120 to 400 sigma Zoom to the Olympics along with my Nikon D7000 and its 18 to 105mm lens, the Sigma was in its padded case and despite arguing was told that as it was over 200mm focal length I could not take it in, so it was taken off me placed in secure storage till I collected it; I bought this lens specifically for the Olympic games and I was SO PISSED OFF.. especially as where I was sitting I could see loads of other spectators using their long lenses....

No mention was made of the 30cm x 20cm X 20cm case max size just the focal length, to be honest I think on reflecting back as it said 400 mm on the lens perhaps they got confused with 30cm being a max and the 400mm focal length....

I will be writing to the organizers to tell them of my complaint as they security staff obviously were not consistent and confiscated my lens wrongly ....